# How to set breakpoint in a dependent xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos

i have a XCode project (my main xcode project which has its executable). It has dependencies on a few other projects (under the Project tab in Detail View, there are a few other xcode project that it depends on).

My question is how can I setup breakpoint in the code of the dependent project?

I tried this, but this does not work
1. open my main xcode project
2. double click one of the dependent xcode project
3. in the source directory, find the file I want to break and add a breakpoint (by click at the side of the border of the editor, a blue 'bookmark thing' shows up)
4. Go back to 'Build and Go', my application does run but it never breaks at the break point I set in #3.

Can someone please help me? I have spent days on this, I can't figure it why.

Thank you.

Comment: You're doing it the right way, so long as the dependent project is built, and the main project links to its build product.

Answer (score 30):

1) Add the breakpoint in your project

2) Go into breakpoints view in xcode (top left besides project navigator) The view's icon is like a breakpoint icon

3) Right click on the required breakpoint and select "Move to" -> "User"

If the breakpoint is under "User" project, then it is accessible by all projects.

Comment: Very usefull thanks. But I wonder:  the breakpoint was in the 'Workspace' section. Souldn't it be already accessible by all project in workspace ?  The fact is: It is not, but I wonder why ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! All those who are building framework and EndAPP(app that uses .framework generated by actual framework project) in separate projects , should use this method , debugging gets easier with this  .

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I've had trouble setting breakpoints with the Xcode GUI, I've managed to do it with the debugger command line (that is to say, the "lldb" prompt in the output window).  For example, to set a breakpoint in source file "client.m" at line 42, type:

```
(lldb) b client.m:42
```

Besides being a fix for this particular problem, debugging on the command-line offers far more flexibility and automatability than any GUI could.  A good place to start would be the [LLDB tutorial](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html).  (Full disclosure: I'm a longtime fan of unix and gdb, so there's some bias here).

Of course, as others have mentioned, make sure the library/dependant project is compiled with debug symbols.  Hope this helps; good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo Jon-Eric here and also add that if you habitually run your project with Cmd+Enter, you should consider switching to Cmd+Y to enable gdb each time.

Answer (score 0):

a few things here...(some obvious some not)

1) be sure that the dependant project is compiled with debug symbols (i'm assuming its a library)

2) be sure that your active executable is linking against the debug version of your dependent library

3) set a breakpoint in your main project just before calling into the entry point of your lib, *and* set a bp on the entry-point of the lib... (in addition to the real breakpoint you are looking to hit...)

I have found that the best way to debug a library is to open the lib project and set the active executable to be the main project, and then just hit "build and debug" directly from the library project.

I hope this helps, good luck, and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with Xcode. The solution for me is to make sure that there is also a breakpoint in the main project that gets hit (as Kent mentions in his third point). I don't understand why this works though.

You should also only set breakpoints in a project when you've got it open. If you don't, they can start misbehaving: still stopping the flow of execution after you've disabled or deleted them, or not working when you think they're enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select 'Build and *Debug*' (for step #4). 'Go' sometimes means 'Run' (breakpoints disabled) and sometimes means 'Debug' (breakpoints enabled).

Also, make sure that you leave the dependent project open while you debug the main project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to kent reply about debug symbols, check COPY_PHASE_STRIP value in the build settings of the main project, and be sure it is set to NO in debug.