# How can I debug in a framework in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two projects, one is the `networkLib` for login and some other network function, the other is the `usingLibDemo`. So I have all the source code of both projects.

The `networkLib` project outputs a framework, called `myNetKit.framework`, which is used by `usingLibDemo`.

[image]

Now I successfully use `myNetKit.framework` to login, but sometimes it crashes, maybe in main() without stack information, but sometimes Xcode gives me the stack info like below:

[image]

So I know where it crashes:

[image]

But the `Utils.m` is not exposed, **how Xcode gets the stack info and the crash line, and eventually open the source file for me?** Because that I have the source code in my disk?

If so, how can I debug the `myNetKit.framework` step by step, when it is not crashed?

Thanks a lot for any tips.

Comment: To those who want to debug framework using breakpoints , visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638520/4525717

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also add the entire library (`networkLib`) project into your project and link the library dynamically by adding dependency in project settings. So you can have all the source code within your project. So you can debug it in run time.

Comment: Thanks, I know that pulling the `networkLib` project into `usingLibDemo` will be easy to debug, for the source code is there. But I wonder how Xcode get the `Utils.m` source file, and the full stack information.

Comment: My guess is that during the build process of the framework debug symbols were not stripped. I believe you then get this kind of information.

Answer (score 28):

If someone would have the same question in future (now I am using Xcode 8):

You can:

1. build your framework project (in this example "networkLib")
2. copy project output ("myNetKit.framework") to destination project ("usingLibDemo")
3. run destination project ("usingLibDemo") on your device
4. stop process
5. launch app from your device manually ("usingLibDemo")
6. open framework project and Attach to Process of your app (launched in step 5). In Xcode 8: Debug->Attach to Process-> Select name of your app.

Don't forget set some breakpoints in your framework project.

Comment: if this doesn't work , check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638520/4525717

Answer (score 7):

When the library is built with all symbols, it contains full paths to the each source file embedded in itself. You can actually see this if you open the .a with a hex viewer. With this in place, the XCode will know how to get to the source file.

Setting breakpoints is somewhat more challenging. You basically have to make XCode slowly discover source files from your library by stepping into methods in those file. Once XCode has opened the file, you can set the breakpoint anywhere in it.

It is a bit painful but it works and you do not have to make the library project a subproject if you do not want to.

Answer (score 6):

The following works considering the **scenario** that you have the framework project separately and added *a.framework* to some *project B*.

1. Go to your project B, add a breakpoint anywhere.
2. Go to the breakpoint view(where all breakpoints can be seen as a list), right click your breakpoint and click move breakpoint to user.
3. Go to *a.framework* and repeat step 1 and 2 but for your framework project.
4. Now switch back to project B and run the project on simulator/device.

You'll now see program stopping at the breakpoints set in the framework as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use XCode Workspace when you deal with multiple framework projects. When you use a workspace, breakpoints will work and you can find your crash without loads of back and forth debugging. It will be much easier to manage your frameworks in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I know that pulling the `networkLib` project into `usingLibDemo` will be easy to debug, for the source code is there. But I wonder how Xcode get the `Utils.m` source file, and the full stack information.

Comment: Because XCode uses reference of whatever files you opened recently. Hence it is able to open Utils.m.

Comment: When you bundle only your framework code in main project, xcode will not be able to access .m files. In your case, it is able to access just because it remembering reference of recently opened files.

Comment: I don't think this is right. There is some build settings that controls embedding the path to the source sode inside the framework. That is how Xcode knows how to get to it...I have not figured out what that setting is yet...if you do I would be interested in knowing

Answer (score -1):

You should debug the project networkLib which outputs the framework separately. The framework do not have app like structure so a framework file within other project can't be debugged.

Comment: It can not be debugged if you have only integrated  the .framework file. You can also try answer by Mathew Varghese

Comment: Thanks, I know that pulling the `networkLib` project into `usingLibDemo` will be easy to debug, for the source code is there. But I wonder how Xcode get the `Utils.m` source file, and the full stack information.