# Undefined symbols in another Xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I asked a question here yesterday about [HOWTO debug in a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15654493/889538).

I have one `networkLib`, and a `usingLibDemo` project.

The answers suggest me to pull the `networkLib` into `usingLibDemo` so that I can debug in the source code.

Now I've tried :

1. Output a framework from `networkLib`, and use the framework in
   `usingLibDemo`. It works.
2. Copy all the source code of `networkLib` into `usingLibDemo`, it
   works again.
3. Drag the `networkLib` project into `usingLibDemo` project, set the
   `Header Search Paths` in the `Build Settings` and set the `Target
   Dependencies` in the `Build Phases`. It fails.

In #3 situation, the project is build successfully when using headers only. For example, I just use the protocol:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <LoginUIDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameText;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordText;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;

- (IBAction)loginBtnDidClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

But when I use the code in the `.m` file :

```
[[LoginBizLogic sharedInstance] loginWithUsername:username password:password tokenLogin:NO uiDelegate:self];
```

Build failed like below :

[image]

The `@interface` of LoginBizLogic, as well as `LoginUIDelegate`, is defined in `LoginBizLogic.h` file, but the `@implementation` is in the 'LoginBizLogic.m' file.

I think the `LoginBizLogic` is not linked properly, and the same with other Class, but I can not figure out where the problem is, or where to config.

Many thanks.

Comment: see my question and try the accepted answer, that worked well for me. [ERROR: Undefined symbols for architecture i386](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157632/error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read Answer From This [Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

> You can get this type of error if your class' .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step of the "Build Phases" tab of your target. Normally Xcode does this for you, but sometimes it loses the plot and you need to add the .m file manually.

**In Your case:**

```
TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m file  ->Build and Run
```

Comment: @iPatel thank you for your valuable help but please make sure don't post duplicate answers here, instead just link that question, FYI duplicate answers will be deleted by community, Hope you got me!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @iPatel

From your answer I know where the problem is:

[image]

and how to explicitly compile imported files, but `networkLib` has too many files to select:

[image]

It's annoying to select 135 items, and I have set the dependency:

[image]

[image]

So I think before compiling `usingLibDemo`, `networkLib` has been compiled.

It is compiled, why symbols not found? -------> Not linked! I import the library for linking :

[image]

That's it! Thanks again.

Comment: please! don't forget to accept the answer whether solution posted by other or self. Once you accept the answer people come to know this problem has been solved and which is the solution,because that makes better stack overflow and your repo too.

Comment: I had the same problem and Linking the binary solved the problem. Thanks