# How to debug the Cocoa Touch Framework (the iphone simulator build)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created a Cocoa Touch Framework and I am testing it with another sample app. Since I am using simulator so I am using framework build which is inside **Debug-iphonesimulator** folder. Sample App and Framework are in different workspaces. I want to debug the framework but I can't. I could debug it sometimes, breakpoints were getting hit but now its not working. What can I do to debug the framework? Something I am missing?

I am using XCode 6.1 and both framework and sample app are written in Objective-C.

I don't want to include framework project inside my sample app project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug in a framework in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654493/how-can-i-debug-in-a-framework-in-xcode)

Comment: @PavelOganesyan I don't want to include my framework project inside my sample app.

Comment: I'd suggest to read all the answers in this thread I provided. There is an answer by @Moonwalker that suits your case. Long story short: build framework with debug symbols and try to open source files of framework by using debugger to step into them from your current project sources.

Comment: Also, here is a link to docs: [iOS Debug Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html)

Comment: @PavelOganesyan Looks like that's exactly what happened to me. I accidentally stepped into a framework method and I could see framework .m file there and could set breakpoints there. I will verify it again and let you know. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @PavelOganesyan I could debug it by stepping into one of framework class method. Once the breakpoint inside your sample app gets hit just step into framework class method, soon as you step into the framework class the .m file is fetched inside the sample project and now just put as many breakpoints as you want in .m file and debug. You have todo the same for every framework class you want to debug. Do we have any other better way? Thanks.