# Why can't I set a breakpoint in my library?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

the goal is to debug a method deep within a library.

We can debug c functions in that same library (as long as they are not in the .m files), but apparently no Objective-C code, or even c code within any .m file.

When I try to set breakpoints manually, (`break set -n`), I get:
`WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.`

The code does get called, the trusty logger confirms that.

My hunch is that debugging information gets lost somewhere along the way: We are building a static library, then another static library ("Framework" style), and finally we are linking this into our app. Yes, that's complicated but, historical reasons, you know.

I have tried to examine the first .a file to see what is going on, but when I try to load it into `lldb` I have to create a target. And target creation fails for either architecture:

`target create -d --arch i386 libFoo.a 
error: 'libFoo.a' doesn't contain the architecture i386`

`target create -d --arch armv7 libFoo.a

error: 'libFoo.a' doesn't contain any 'remote-ios' platform architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7f, armv7k, armv7s, armv7m, armv7em, armv6m, armv6, armv5, armv4, arm, thumbv7, thumbv7k, thumbv7s, thumbv7f, thumbv7m, thumbv7em, thumbv6m, thumbv6, thumbv5, thumbv4t, thumb`

`lipo -info libFoo.a
Architectures in the fat file: libFoo.a are: armv7 i386`

Does anyone have a good idea how to best tackle this issue? The code is definitely linked, working, but lldb can not set breakpoints.

Thanks a lot

Addendum:

I have created the most simple setup I could think of, and I see very, very odd results:

If I try to lookup certain things, some will return a file and a line number, others will not:

`image lookup -s Foo::faz()
1 symbols match 'Foo::faz()' in […]/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Test.app/Test:
        Address: Test[0x00010334] (Test.__TEXT.__text + 22060)
        Summary: Test'Foo::faz() at Foo.cpp:858
image lookup -s FazBar
1 symbols match 'FazBar' in […]/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Test.app/Test:
        Address: Test[0x00038eb4] (Test.__TEXT.__text + 188844)
        Summary: Test'FazBar`

Trying to set breakpoints in the corresponding files yields, well, expected results:

`(lldb) break set -f Foo.cpp -l 877
Breakpoint 5: where = Test'Foo::faz() + 76 at Foo.cpp:877, address = 0x000cb380
(lldb) break set -f bar.c -l 585
Breakpoint 6: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.`

How can I dig into the .a file to see why certain files are not found?

Comment: are you using exception breakpoint

Comment: No, regular breakpoints

Comment: This seems to have been asked a few times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025732/debugging-a-library-with-xcode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924628/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-a-dependent-xcode-project

Comment: fwiw I don't think `target create -d --arch i386 libFoo.a` is going to work in lldb - this has nothing to do with your debug info being turned on or not.  These are called "static libraries" (really, ranlib archives) - they are like a zip of `.o` files, not a single binary.  lldb won't accept them as a binary image.  You can run lldb on a `.o` file, a `.dylib`, an executable, app, bundle, etc., but I don't think anyone has ever made it accept ranlib archives.  No technical reason it couldn't be done; lldb would basically load all the `.o` files as separate binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone (actually not me, had the absolutely bright idea of setting
`GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = NO`
somewhere hidden deep.

Setting it to yes, well, you guessed it, solves the issue

Alex

Answer (score 0):

[image]

set exception break point like above

go to  brekpoint navigation click on + and slecte add exception brak point

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how that helps me. Why would I need to set a breakpoint on exceptions? Or do you mean I should throw exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using DYLD_BIND_AT_LOAD environment variable set. This should disable lazy binding, which often fails to hit symbolic breaküpints